# Text ::Selection 100% not transparent?

Tags: css, transparency, selection

I would like to know if there is a solution for ::selection without any transparency on the background color of the selected text.

In my JSfiddle example i got a white text on a black background, and if i select the text (f.e. to copy it) i want it to show up negativly ( when selected, the text should be black and the selection itself that uses to be bright blue, should be white, but without transparency)

I would be happy when there will be found a solution :)

http://jsfiddle.net/jqSuP/1/

```
::-moz-selection {
     color: black;  
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
}
::selection { 
    color: black;  
    background: rgba(255,255,255,1);  
}
body{
    background-color:#000
}
p{
    16px;
    color:white;
}
```

Comment: Your p element should be `font-size: 16px` by the way

Comment: of course it should :) thanks for advice :)

Comment: This looks like it's been done on purpose in Webkit and Blink -- it works fine in Firefox, IE 9, and Opera 12 (pre-Blink,) and it fails in Opera 16, Chrome and Safari. Probably nothing you can do about it ...

Comment: Can you clarify, you say when selected, the background of the selected text should be bright blue? I don't see any bright blue in your see currently.

Comment: @Pippin OP mentions the original highlight background is bright blue, not that it should be. OP wants white bg and black text, the inverse of the unselected colours.

Comment: sorry, i've meant like the original selection whithout some extra code :)

Comment: Ah, the uses (that should be used), was confusing. Thanks @setek